# Why $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI' NOT working with IF condition

Tags: php, server, echo, request-uri

My webpage url is http://example.com/blog/

When I echo it is showing the correct result as blog.

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

>>blog
```

But, when I use in if condition

```
<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']== 'blog') echo 'class="Margincls"';?>
```

it doesn't return anything, tried with basename and strtolower as well

Answer (score 1):

If your url is `http://example.com/blog/`, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` should be `/blog/`. I checked on my environment - Apache, PHP 5.6.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong quotations. Copy and paste this:

```
<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']== 'blog') echo 'class="Margincls"';?>
```

Comment: sorry, doesn't work. probably it showing wrong quotes because of my keyboard smart quotes settings.

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] also returns the first forward slash, so you need to check this when equating.

```
<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']== '/blog') echo 'class="Margincls"';?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']== '/blog/') echo 'class="Margincls"';?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your site is live. if you use only $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] it will work only in localhost.

You can try this.

```
  if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/blog/') == true){
         echo "Hello world";
    }else{
        echo "Hello WOrld 2";
    }
```